# How can i call function in blazor and pass curent component object from which is called

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I like to call function in blazor. I have blazor page and one class. For example like bottom. So curentlty  call gVC function with "this" and component name. But "this" parameter is main component not component from where i call DxMenuItem.

So is it possible to call or get in my function, which component called it. So that i do not neeed to pass component name, text etc..but i can call this function like `g.gVC(this)` in any component and than in fucntion  get information of component.

```
@inject Globals g
<h3>Component</h3>

...

<DxMenuItem Name="dxmEMEdit" Visible=@g.gVC(this, "dxmEMEdit") NavigateUrl="Employee/EmployeeEdit" Text="Šome text" CssClass="menu-item" IconCssClass="icon weather-icon"></DxMenuItem>
...

@code {

}
```

```
class Globals 
............

        public bool gVC(object cont,string nameObj)
        {
            here i like to get name from which component function is callled, nad other parameter etc..
            cont.Text
            cont. component name


        }
```

So is it possible to call or get in my function, which component called it. So that i do not neeed to pass component name, text etc..but i can call this function like `g.gVC(this)` in any component and than in fucntion  get information of component.

Answer (score 0):

The direct approach requires an @ref to get the child component:

```cs
<DxMenuItem @ref="item1" Name="dxmEMEdit" Visible=@g.gVC(item1, "dxmEMEdit") ...></DxMenuItem>
...
@code {
 DxMenuItem item1;
}
```

The indirect approach would be to have ViewModels for the MenuItems (and everything else). Then it could look like

```html
<DxMenuItem Name="@item1.Name" Visible=@g.gVC(item1) NavigateUrl="@item1.Url" ...></DxMenuItem>

@code {
 MenuItemViewModel item1 = ...;
}
```

This could improve your architecture overall, but it depends.

Comment: this could work, but if i have more diffrent components on difrent pages or same pages, then will have lot of work to reference all of them. Is there any shorter way. I like to simplify this call

Comment: I've added a 2nd part about ViewModels. But your sample is too small to to say anything useful about architecture.